# Fix history of a remote git-svn branch that is missing its branch point

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm using `git-svn` to interact with a remote `svn` repsitory that follows the traditional layout of trunk, tags, and branches.

There's a branch in `svn` that `git` has missed the history of. I know the history to be:

```
r0--r1--r2---r4---r6 remotes/trunk
         \
           r3---r5-- remotes/BRANCH_NAME
```

But git seems to have missed the branch point and thinks the history is:

```
r0---r1---r2-----r4---r6 remotes/trunk

r0'--r1'--r2'--r3--r5--- remotes/BRANCH_NAME
```

Where `r0'`, `r1'`, and `r2'` are copies of `r0`, `r1`, and `r2` that appear in git, but not in svn. In svn there is exactly one `r0` commit.

The first entry in `.git/svn/refs/remotes/BRANCH_NAME/unhandled.log.gz` may offer the experts a clue:

```
r3
  +dir_prop: . svn:mergeinfo /product/trunk/src_py:371-436%2C438-532
```

How do I get git to realise that `r3` was branched from `r2` and do away with `r2'`, `r1'`, and `r0'`?

---

For extra credit: Is there a general way to rewrite git's view of svn history, that won't get clobbered by `git svn fetch` et al?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be the `git-svn-id` URL in the log messages that was different, thus altering the SHA1. E.g. `http://hostname/repo` and `http://hostname.org.ext/repo`.

I used `git branch-filter --msg-filter` to update the `git-svn-id` marker in every commit and the problem went away. (And of course ran `git gc` to scrub all the redundant commits from my repo)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) instead of git-svn. It handles such SHA1-changes correctly.

Or alternatively, if you have an access to the SVN serevr, install [SubGit](http://subgit.com) into it. SubGit will create a linked Git repository that you can work with. SVN and Git repositories will always be in sync. So you can use just Git interface.