# Debugging why git (svn) rebase does not detect patch (noop)?

Tags: git, git-svn

I have a `git-svn` repository ([Unexpected merge error in a git svn system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050377/unexpected-merge-error-in-a-git-svn-system)); it has a remote called `origingit` referring to another git repo, in addition to `git-svn` which refers to an SVN repo.

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/git-svn
$ git remote show 
origingit
$ tree .git/refs/{heads,remotes}
.git/refs/heads
└── master
.git/refs/remotes
├── git-svn
└── origingit
```

Here is the problem: when I do

```
git pull --rebase origingit master
```

... `git` splits the tree, so that all commits from origingit that have not been part of the original `git svn clone` lose their `git-svn-id` (are "local", see [git-svn-id is missing from some commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571730/git-svn-id-is-missing-from-some-commits)); in this case, the relevant commits look like this (they all have "null edit" in the name):

```
$ git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all --date-order | grep 'null edit'
* cae158d (git-svn) : null edit A06
* 8f79edf : null edit A05
* 0c7373e : null edit A04
* b4bf336 : null edit A03
* e05cfc6 : null edit A02
| * e0c6823 (HEAD, master) : null edit A07
| * 03ed433 : null edit A06
| * de3bd53 : null edit A05
| * 65bf738 : null edit A04
| * 62ab3f6 : null edit A03
* | 964b300 : null edit A01
| * 14f5aba : null edit A02
| * f0ef194 : null edit A01
```

Note that `master` has picked up the latest "null edit A07", which came in from origingit.

When I do

```
git svn rebase
```

... all those commits present in the SVN repository should get a `git-svn-id`, and those not yet comitted to SVN don't - but are listed after (in time, or first in order) the `git-svn-id` ones in `git log`; so on the next `git svn dcommit`, those local would be comitted to SVN. However, in this particular case, I get the `log --graph` as:

```
* cae158d (HEAD, git-svn, master) : null edit A06
* 8f79edf : null edit A05
* 0c7373e : null edit A04
* b4bf336 : null edit A03
* e05cfc6 : null edit A02
* 964b300 : null edit A01
```

In fact, here `git svn rebase` outputs to stdout just "First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it..." and exits; otherwise, it usually says "Applying: ..." which apparently refers to patches (and ... is the commit message for those local), and in that case, the expected log would be:

```
* xxxxxxx (HEAD, master) : null edit A07
* cae158d (git-svn) : null edit A06
* 8f79edf : null edit A05
* 0c7373e : null edit A04
* b4bf336 : null edit A03
* e05cfc6 : null edit A02
* 964b300 : null edit A01
```

So - even if `null edit A07` is clearly a valid commit in the origingit repo, and comes after `null edit A06` one (which is also present in SVN), `git svn rebase` fails to apply this patch. Why - and how is it even possible?

In any case, from this point, I can do `git pull --rebase ...` and get to the previous state shown.

Here it would be very nice if there was some debugging facility, which could tell you how `git rebase` goes through each commit and decides what to do - but unfortunately, `--verbose` just dumps a list of files changed between the last git-svn-id commit and the latest HEAD, so it doesn't help much.

Adding some printouts to `/usr/lib/git-core/git-svn`, I could see that `git svn rebase` ultimately calls `git rebase refs/remotes/git-svn`; so I tried to add interactive to it:

```
$ git pull --rebase origingit master
...
$ git rebase --interactive  refs/remotes/git-svn
```

... and it shows:

```
noop

# Rebase cae158d..e0c6823 onto cae158d
#
# Commands: [...]
```

So, applying patches doesn't happen during rebase, because it doesn't find that any patches should be made. But how is that possible - noting that  cae158d is the SHA of "null edit A06" within `git-svn` (and is present both on SVN and in origingit), while e0c6823 is the SHA of "null edit A07" which came in from origingit - where it stands unequivocally and without a problem as a commit (meaning, there must be an actual change from previous revision) after the "null edit A06"??

So, how can I inspect why this happens - and ultimately, how can I force git to recognize during `git svn rebase` that there is indeed a patch there?

Comment: Just a note: there is a [GIT_TRACE environment variable](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/#_environment_variables) that does reveal a lot, but I best I could get to is `built-in: git 'format-patch' '-k' '--stdout' '--full-index' '--ignore-if-in-upstream'`; apparently it is `--ignore-if-in-upstream` that makes the patch not appear; however, as `format-patch` is built-in, it cannot be traced further with this method...